# Creating a table record - Google Spreadsheets API

Tags: java, google-api, google-sheets

I am trying to learn how to use the Google Spreadsheets API through the Developer's Guide: Java. My application can authenticate to the spreadsheets service,retrieve a worksheet-based feed and create a table. The next step would be to create a table record what I am trying to do. My problem is when I run the application I obtain this error :

```
Service failure
com.google.gdata.util.InvalidEntryException: Bad Request
[Line 1, Column 429, element entry] Required extension element  http://schemas.google.com/spreadsheets/2006:header not found.
```

This is the code part for the creation of the table :

```
//Creating a table record
String nameValuePairs = "Column A=Rosa";
RecordEntry entryToChange = new RecordEntry();
// Split first by the commas between the different fields.
for (String nameValuePair : nameValuePairs.split(",")) {
    // Then split by the equal sign.
    String[] parts = nameValuePair.split("=", 2);
    String name = parts[0]; // such as "name"
    String value = parts[1]; // such as "Fred"

    entryToChange.addField(new Field(null, name, value));         
}
try {
    myService.insert(tableFeedUrl, entryToChange);
} catch (IOException e) {
    System.err.println("I/0 problem");
    e.printStackTrace();
} catch (ServiceException e) {
    System.err.println("Service failure");
    e.printStackTrace();
}
```

tableFeedUrl :

```
tableFeedUrl = factory.getTableFeedUrl(entry.getKey());
```

entry :

```
entry = spreadsheets.get(0);
```

Apparently the problem come from :

```
myService.insert(tableFeedUrl, entryToChange);
```

but I am not sure and I don't understand why...

Thank you for your help.

Comment: Will you please help here : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4883123/how-do-you-access-spreadsheet-service-using-a-java-client

Comment: Can you use this to "insert a row in to a google spreadsheet" rather than simply append new rows to the end. See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14209079/insert-a-row-in-to-a-google-spreadsheet-using-the-api-with-java

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have found the solution. I answer my own question for those who will have the same problem.

I use :

```
myService.insert(tableFeedUrl, entryToChange);
```

"tableFeedUrl" corresponds to :

```
http://spreadsheets.google.com/feeds/<key>/tables/
```

this's not the right link to access to the table ([the doc](http://code.google.com/intl/uk-UA/apis/spreadsheets/data/3.0/reference.html#TableRecordFeed)).

But in the [Java developers guide](http://code.google.com/intl/fr/apis/spreadsheets/data/3.0/developers_guide_java.html) it's notice we have to use :

```
myService.insert(recordFeedUrl, entryToChange);
```

"recordFeedUrl" results from :

```
URL recordFeedUrl = tableEntry.getRecordFeedUrl();
```

But the method : getRecordFeedUrl() doesn't exist... ([the doc](http://code.google.com/intl/fr/apis/gdata/javadoc/com/google/gdata/data/spreadsheet/TableEntry.html))

The solution is to create manually the URL :

```
recordFeedUrl = new URL(table.getId().toString().replace("tables", "records"));
```

So the URL corresponds to the table :

```
https://spreadsheets.google.com/feeds/<key>/records/60
```

"60" corresponds to the table number.

I hope it will help!