# Insert New Data to Top of Google Spreadsheet using Google Sheets API v4

Tags: java, google-sheets, google-sheets-api

I'm using Google Sheets to keep track of recent orders on my website. I'd like to add details of each new order to a Google spreadsheet and have the most recent order details show up on top of the sheet and the older entries on the bottom.

I'm aware I could append new row after last row without knowing/providing Google with the row number using the following code:

```
// INSERTS NEW DATA AFTER LAST ROW
ValueRange body = new ValueRange().setValues(writeData);
AppendValuesResponse appendValuesResponse =
        service.spreadsheets().values().append(spreadsheetId, range, body)
                .setValueInputOption(valueInputOption)
                .execute();
```

However, this would mean that the newer entries are added to the bottom of the sheet instead of the top. My requirements are exactly the opposite. I need to add/append newer entries to the top of the sheet and have older entries move to the bottom.

Is there a way to accomplish this natively using the API?

Comment: https://developers.google.com/sheets/api/reference/rest/v4/spreadsheets/request#UpdateCellsRequest ??

Answer (score 0):

There is no direct method for this. Your closest chance to manipulate the order of data in your sheet is to [Sort a range with multiple sorting specifications](https://developers.google.com/sheets/api/samples/data#sort_a_range_with_multiple_sorting_specifications) or make it that the data is added to sheet from bottom (like A+ctr to A+ctr by use of a decrementing variable counter 10-1).

Answer (score 0):

I had a very similar requirement and I am sharing how I solved it.

I know the number of rows I want to insert at the top. I inserted blank rows at the top under the headers. I set `startIndex` and `endIndex` based on row count and request a BatchUpdate on the Spreadsheet. Then updated the range (which are now blank after this call) with values.

```
    log.trace("Inserting Blank Row At the Top of Sheet");

    DimensionRange dimensionRange = new DimensionRange();
    dimensionRange.setDimension("ROWS");
    dimensionRange.setStartIndex(1); // depends on your requirement
    dimensionRange.setEndIndex(10);  // depends on your requirement

    InsertDimensionRequest insertDimension = new InsertDimensionRequest();
    insertDimension.setRange(dimensionRange);

    Request insertionRequest = new Request();
    insertionRequest.setInsertDimension(insertDimension);

    BatchUpdateSpreadsheetRequest batchUpdateSpreadsheetRequest = new BatchUpdateSpreadsheetRequest();
    batchUpdateSpreadsheetRequest.setRequests(Arrays.asList(insertionRequest));

    try {
        BatchUpdateSpreadsheetResponse execute = sheets.spreadsheets()
                .batchUpdate(spreadsheetId, batchUpdateSpreadsheetRequest)
                .execute();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        log.error("Exception Occurred While Inserting Blank Row - Details: {}", e.getMessage());
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
```

Google Reference Doc: [InsertDimensionRequest - Sheets API Reference](https://developers.google.com/sheets/api/reference/rest/v4/spreadsheets/request?hl=en#InsertDimensionRequest)

Note: This answer for C# helped me come with this Java solution: https://stackoverflow.com/a/53587428/7878602