# Insert row on top in Google Sheet with API version 4

Tags: c#, .net, google-sheets-api

I am trying to insert rows in google sheet with c# console application using Google Sheets API v4. I am able to insert row with below code but not able to insert on top.

I want that every row inserted should be inserted on top and other existing row should shift down.

```
 SpreadsheetsResource.ValuesResource.UpdateRequest request =
        service.Spreadsheets.Values.Update(new ValueRange() { Values = values }, spreadsheetId, newRange);
 request.ValueInputOption = SpreadsheetsResource.ValuesResource.UpdateRequest.ValueInputOptionEnum.USERENTERED;

 var response = request.Execute();
```

Comment: If you want to insert rows, then use an insert rows request: https://developers.google.com/sheets/api/reference/rest/v4/spreadsheets/request#insertdimensionrequest

Comment: For Java look at https://stackoverflow.com/a/66253257/7878602

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I tried following and it worked for me:-

```
       InsertDimensionRequest insertRow = new InsertDimensionRequest();
            insertRow.Range = new DimensionRange()
            {
                SheetId = MySheetID,
                Dimension = "ROWS",
                StartIndex = 1,
                EndIndex = 2
            };

            PasteDataRequest data = new PasteDataRequest
            {
                Data = string.Join(",", values[0]),
                Delimiter = ",",
                Coordinate = new GridCoordinate
                {
                    ColumnIndex = 0,
                    RowIndex = 1,
                    SheetId = MySheetID
                },
            };

            BatchUpdateSpreadsheetRequest r = new BatchUpdateSpreadsheetRequest()
            {
                Requests = new List<Request>
                {
                    new Request{ InsertDimension = insertRow },
                    new Request{ PasteData = data }
                }
            };

            BatchUpdateSpreadsheetResponse response1 = service.Spreadsheets.BatchUpdate(r, spreadsheetId).Execute();
```

Thanks @tehhowch

Comment: Thanks for sharing, this helped me to come up with a solution for Java.